# How to update line dynamically in VBScript?

Tags: file, if-statement, vbscript

I am writing a script, and I wanted to know how I can read a txt file and find the line and then replace it.

For example, if I have a txt file called ImportParms.txt which has some parameter lines in it that look like this:

```
cmdFile=E:\Jobs\UPCS\Parms\ImportParms.upcs_cmd
Process=StandardImport
LogFile=e:\JOBS\UPCS\Logs\ImportLog.txt
File=E:\jobs\UPCS\TestImportFile.txt
ImportRejects=No
RenameToOld=No
RenameDateStamp=No
ResultsReport="Public Reports\ImportResult"
LinkExisting=Custom1
```

I want to update the line that says `File=something.txt` every time it runs. So that instead of having

```
sCmd = sBotCmd & " file=""" & sUtilOut &""" "
```

it will just say

```
sCmd = sBotCmd
```

From the part of my code that runs the exe which looks like this:

```
'Run processbot to update
Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile(sUtilOut)
If oFile.Size <> 0 Then
    strFile = sWORK & "\parms\" & BOTPARMFILE
    Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        'If first for characters = "file" 
            'delete this line
            strFile.Write "file=" & sUtilOut
        'End If
    Loop
    objFile.Close 

    sBotCmd = """"& sWORK & "\" & BOTPROG & """ " _
              & " cmdFile=""" & sWORK & "\parms\" & BOTPARMFILE & """ "

    sCmd = sBotCmd
    Call OutMsg(isVerbose, isVerbose, sSysLog, "Command: " & sCmd)
    iRetC = oShell.Run(sCmd, 0, True)
    Call OutMsg(isVerbose, isVerbose, sSysLog, "RC: " & iRetC)
    If iRetC <> 0 Then
        Call OutMsg(isVerbose, isVerbose, sSysLog, "Exiting with code " _
            & rcPROCBOT)
        WScript.Quit(rcPROCBOT)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify files in-place. Since your file is small just read its entire content, do your modifications, then write it back.

Replace this:

```
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    'If first for characters = "file" 
        'delete this line
        strFile.Write "file=" & sUtilOut
    'End If
Loop
objFile.Close
```

with this:

```
txt = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "^(File=)[^\r\n]*"
re.MultiLine  = True

fso.OpenTextFile(strFile, 2).Write re.Replace(txt, "$1" & sUtilOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is what I was looking for, I didn't realize I could use RegEx in VBScript, I was thinking I'd have to re-write the whole file, but I was going to do it line by line, and then skip that one and replace it, but this way looks much better!